# Magento 2: PDF set page margins for Invoice

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf, zend-framework

I added a footer to my invoices, this works fine.

```
private function _insertFooter($page) {

    $this->_setFontRegular($page, 8);

    $this->y = 100;
    $page->drawLine(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y);
    $this->y -= 15;

    $page->drawText('My Shop', 30, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText('Address', 30, $this->y - 10, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText('ZIP City', 30, $this->y - 20, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText('Country', 30, $this->y - 30, 'UTF-8');
    $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);

}
```

I add this function into the getPDF() function

/**
     * Return PDF document
     *
     * @param array|Collection $invoices
     * @return \Zend_Pdf
     */
    public function getPdf($invoices = [])
    {
        $this->_beforeGetPdf();
        $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

```
    $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
    $this->_setPdf($pdf);
    $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        [...]
    }
    $this->_insertFooter($page); // <-- my footer stuff
    $this->_afterGetPdf();
    return $pdf;
}
```

Perfect, the footer is shown. But when there are several items in this invoice (so the table is too long), the product table overlaps the footer. I guess it would be easy to set page margins (like in html2pdf)... But how can I do that - I'm not fimilar with Zend yet. Or is this possible?